# Aggregate multiple columns by values in another column in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame (sp.table) containing 31 columns with species names along the top containing abundance data of that species from different samples. I also have a Cruise column containing a Cruise ID for the Cruise within which the samples were recorded. I would like to aggregate each column by Cruise so I have the same number of columns but fewer rows.

I have tried:

```
a <- aggregate(sp.table[,1:31]~ sp.table$Cruise), FUN = sum)
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: It's better to actually post a sample of your data rather than describe it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are only 32 columns, the below code should work

```
 res1 <- aggregate(.~Cruise, sp.table, FUN=sum)
```

Or else

```
 res2 <- aggregate(sp.table[1:31], list(Cruise=sp.table$Cruise),
                                 FUN = sum)
```

In case,if there are `NAs`

```
 res3 <-  aggregate(.~Cruise, sp.table,
                  FUN=sum, na.rm=TRUE, na.action=na.pass)
```

In case the `sum` is only needed for a subset of columns

```
 resSub <- aggregate(cbind(X1,X2)~Cruise,sp.table, FUN = sum)
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
sp.table <- data.frame(matrix(sample(1:20, 31*10, replace=TRUE), 
          ncol=31), Cruise=LETTERS[1:2], stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```